# Paytm is not working with production API key in React Native

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway, payment, paytm

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paytm for Paytm integration in React Native. With test API keys, it's working fine but with production API key it's giving an error. Here are the details I am using to initiate payment:

```
var details = {
        mode: "Production",
        orderId: "r_7_3",
        mid: "*****",
        custId: "001",
        channel: "WAP",
        industryType: "Retail",
        website: "DEFAULT",
        amount: "1",
        email: "test@gmail.com",
        phone: "1234567890",
        callback: "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=r_7_3",
        checksumhash: "***********"};
```

I checked in Android native demo app, it's working fine for test as well as production API keys.

Comment: Please specify the error that you're getting

Comment: @Nizam please check this https://drive.google.com/file/d/156N04Z5KkugEcaz50uhji1PungbV7DUZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @RiddhiBalbhadra can you share your payment functions? or can you share your staging mode code?